# Will windows 10 wakeup my pc for an Alarm

Tags: windows-10, wake-up, cortana, alarm

Basic question.
My pc is setup to sleep after an hour idle...
If a alarm is setup with cortana for the next morning, will the alarm app wakeup the pc so it can perform the alarm ?

Just need a quick awneser really cuz i will eventually know if it works tom morning and if i lose my job or not :P haha

Comment: What up ***cuz*** and just be***cause*** me and my ***cous***in are chilling with our PC alarm clock.... wake up!!!   Seriously though, are you using a specific alarm clock app or what?

Comment: What's wrong with trying it to see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

The build-in Alarm&Clock app will not wake up the computer when it's in sleep mode, unless you configure the task scheduler waking up your laptop at a certain time and start Alarm app for notification then.

Comment: Yes i am using the windows 10 alarm app. I will go on and start tweeking the settings to make the pc wakeup to let the alarm app do it`s work,